# Return value from a callback function.

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to implement a security routine to verify passwords. The function easyPbkdf2 works just fine but I need to return the boolean value of **valid**. Little help please, I am having troubles with the scope.
Thanks in advance.

```
userSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function(password) {
    easyPbkdf2 = new EasyPbkdf2(options);
    easyPbkdf2.verify(this.password_salt, this.password_hash, password, function(err, valid) {
        console.log(valid);
});
return valid; // This doesn't work...[ReferenceError: valid is not defined]
}
```

Comment: Placee your `return valid` just after the `console.log(valid)`.

Comment: Your `return` is outside of your function.

Comment: Trying to return with a value from an asynchronous method? Got a scope issue.

Comment: Yes. But if I put the return inside the "verify" function, how can I return the value to the most outside function?

Comment: @DSoles79 - What you're asking for is impossible. You cannot return the value from an async method. You must use callbacks.

Comment: You cannot return an asynchronously obtained value from a synchronous function call.  You must use callbacks to communicate an async result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EasyPbkdf2.verify() is asynchronous.  Return the value won't work.  You need to pass a callback function to return the value.  Something like this:

```
userSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function(password, callback) {
    var easyPbkdf2 = new EasyPbkdf2(options);
    easyPbkdf2.verify(this.password_salt, this.password_hash, password, callback);
};


// how to call it
userSchema.methods.verifyPassword(password, function(err, valid) {
    if (err) {
        // do something such as throwing error
    }
    console.log(valid);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben this solved my problem. I was using just one callback. Now I see that two callbacks are needed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Valid is being assigned inside the easypbkdf2 function, but you are returning the value oitside the function, hence it isnt defined. You probably need to return valid inside the function where you are consoling to see valid. Let me know if it works out for you

Comment: I try this but then the first function didn't return the value to the verifyPassword method. The function who must return the true/false value is the first one.